# Is there an equivalent to a member-wise initialization list in PHP?

Tags: php, oop, initialization

I'd like to start with a little background, in case anyone has any better ideas for design.

I'm looking to create a database class that connects to a database at construction. I would use functions to call the database, to get what I want. The database connection would be closed at destruction.

Since I'm connecting in construction, I'd like to use some properties as part of the mysql_connect... but they're not initialized until construction. I was wondering if there is a way to initialize member variables like a member-wise initialization list in C++, but in PHP.

Comment: I don't know C++ that well so I don't know the concept you talk about, but the usual way in PHP would be to pass those parameters to the constructor: `$var = new db("localhost", "username", "dbname", "password");`

Comment: I could pass the parameters to the constructor... but then all my other classes would need to know all the information every time I want to use my database. It seems like too much duplication of information for an elegant design -Theino

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create a configuration array and pass that to the database class

```
$config = array(...);
$db = new db( $config );

class db {

    function __construct( array $config ) {
        if ( $config ) {
            $this->db_name = $config['db_name'];
            .....
        }
    }

}
```

If your other classes need the info they can use the array as well. Basically the [registry pattern](http://www.phppatterns.com/docs/design/the_registry).

Comment: Very helpful Galen. This looks like the best solution I have found to my problem... and some interesting reading as well!

Thanks for your help -Theino

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to have class constants. I am not sure, if this is exactly what you want, but they maybe close to solving your problem.
[PHP Class Constants](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.constants.php)

Comment: I've looked at class constants, but it looks like I can't make a private constant in PHP! Correct me if I'm wrong, but this is what I've read. I feel wrong making a public constant that is my database password.

-Theino